# Qual servidor escolher para realizar upload e download de arquivos?

Tags: web-service, servidor

Estou terminando um site de upload de e download de arquivos musicais, e não entendo muito sobre servidores, e gostaria da opinião de alguém que entenda o processo, e se tiver algum artigo na internet sobre o assunto, que possa me indicar, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Por que não o seu próprio? O que você pagou para hospedar?

Comment: Ainda não hospedei, mas criar um próprio não requer medidas mais profissionais e mais gastos ?

Comment: Desculpa expressei errado sobre o seu próprio, eu falei em pagar um para ser seu ^^. seguinte...quantos megas pretende utilizar e em qual frenquencia de tempo?

Comment: Já viu os gratuitos?

Comment: Para um site tipo o palcomp3, acho que 500Gb seria o bastante, de inicio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Servidor onde o site está hospedado -** Se você está fazendo um site e disse que está quase pronto, vai precisar de um servidor para hospeda-lo, óbvio. Então aconselho a você organizar seus áudios no próprio servidor, pois o cliente se sentirá mais seguro e confiará mais no que está baixando quando clicar em um link e baixa-lo olhando para a sua página web. A king host cobra `R$ 77,60/mês²` 25 GB de espaço para o site. Com tráfego de 900 GB.